# Cover one finite subset of integers by another one

Tags: additive-combinatorics

Let $A$, $B$ be two finite subsets of integers. We denote by $C(A, B)$ the minimum number of shifts of $A$ to cover $B$. More formally, it can be written as

$$
C(A, B)=\min\{|S|: S\subseteq B-A,~\text{such that}~B\subseteq A+S\}.
$$

The trivial lower bound for $C(A, B)$ is $|B|/|A|$. Random simulations show the following upper bound

$$
C(A, B)\leq \frac{|B-A|}{|A|}.
$$

I googled covering number stuff, but do not see this upper bound. Inductive argument should work, but I can not prove it. Anybody knows this result or ideas to prove it?

Comment: I get |B| as an upper bound, with B an interval and A sparse enough.  Do you have conditions on A and B?

Comment: The standard Ruzsa covering lemma says that $B$ can be covered by at most $|B-A|/|A|$ translates of the set $A-A$. I am pretty sure that you cannot replace here $A-A$ with $A$, although I cannot think of a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: Exercise 2.4.1 in Tao and Vu gives a counterexample, showing you need at least an extra log factor - take $B$ to be $[1,N]$ and $A$ to be a random subset of $[1,N]$, taking elements with probability $3/4$.

Comment: In general, we indeed can not replace $A-A$ by $A$ in Ruzsa's covering lemma. It is not hard to figure out counter examples of the conjecture I posted for cyclic groups. Actually, I did not believe such an upper bound in the beginning. I tried some examples by hand and also did random simulations, all show that it holds in the setting of finite subsets of integers. I am thinking about Exercise 2.4.1 in Tao and Vu's book to see that does it really provide a counter example.